# Converting a list of XViewModel into a list of X

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a list of FilterViewModel that I display in a treeview. A FilterViewModel has a collection of Children which are also of type FilterViewModel, an each FilterViewModel is "checkable". Like so:

```
public abstract class FilterViewModel
{
       public string ID { get; set; }
       public virtual IEnumerable<FilterViewModel> Children { get; private set; }
       public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
       private FilterModel _filter;


       public FilterViewModel(Filter filter, IEnumerable<Filter> checkedFilters)
       {
           _filter = filter;
           CheckFilters(checkedFilters);
       }       
}
```

When the treeview is created, the corresponding filters are checked like so:

```
    private void SetChildrenChecked(IEnumerable<Filter> filters,  
          IEnumerable<FilterViewModel> visibleList)
    {

        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            foreach (var filterVM in visibleList
                .Where(filterVM => filter.ID == filterVM.ID))
            {
                if (filter.Children.Any())
                {
                    SetChildrenChecked(filter.Children, filterVM.Children);
                }
                else
                {
                    filterVM.Children.ForEach(c => c.IsChecked = true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I am struggling to figure out the best way to do the opposite - to return a List of  for every checked FilterViewModel in the hierarchy.

Does anyone know a quick solution? I'm assuming it would be bad practice and may confuse matters to expose the Model on the ViewModel...

Answer (score 1):

I would not have said it was bad practice to expose the `Model` object on the `ViewModel` so long as you didn't try use it from the `View`.

However, you should be able to do this in much the same way as setting the `IsChecked` if you already have the list of all `Filter` objects:

```
private IEnumerable<Filter> GetChildrenChecked(IEnumerable<Filter> filters, IEnumerable<FilterViewModel> visibleList)
{
    List<Filter> returnValue = new List<Filter>();
    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        foreach (var filterVM in visibleList
            .Where(filterVM => filter.ID == filterVM.ID))
        {
           if (filter.Children.Any())
            {
                returnValue.AddRange(GetChildrenChecked(filter.Children, filterVM.Children));
            }
            else
            {
                if (filterVM.IsChecked)
                 returnValue.Add(filter);
            }
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```